# Is IDbCommandInterceptor in EntityFramework 6 thread safe

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

Is a IDbCommandInterceptor instance considered thread-safe when registered with the DbInterception add method? I have implemented a class that conforms to the IDbCommandInterceptor interface and am tracking the start time of a command when one of the executing methods are invoked compared to the stop time when the corresponding executed method is called. I'm storing this information in a private ivar list and need to know if what I'm doing is safe.

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out the IDbCommandInterceptor is not thread safe as it is only instantiated once.

Comment: They should have provided some sort of correlation, that would have made things easy.