# IDbCommandInterceptor query monitoring

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have created a query interceptor in EF6:

```
public class QueryCommandInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    private readonly Stopwatch _stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

    public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
        {
            _stopWatch.Restart();
        }

        public void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
        {
            _stopWatch.Stop();
        }
}
```

Is it possible for two Executing methods to start before its corresponding Executed method finishes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean, is this `IDbCommandInterceptor` thread safe?

[Is IDbCommandInterceptor in EntityFramework 6 thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431659/is-idbcommandinterceptor-in-entityframework-6-thread-safe)

The answer is no.

Comment: How does Database.Log work then? It provides query timing information. If you look at their source code it is using a Stopwatch variable as well.

Comment: What do you mean "How does `Database.Log`" work? What is `Database.Log`? If you want to ask, how do you fix this? Its simple, you have access to both the `DbCommand` and the `DbCommandInterceptionContext` in both cases. You can use a dictionary to store the start times of each `DbCommand`.